# How to verify that post to website is coming from a specific purchased iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, itunes, verification, asihttprequest

I have an iPhone application that posts data to a web application ... and I want to only accept data posted from an iPhone application that was purchased from the iTunes store.

Is there a way to do this?  Is there something (or somethings) I can pass from the iPhone app to the web application that I can use to do such verification?

Thanks much

btw, using the asihttprequest library to handle requests/responses.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple doesn't provide any information about who purchased your app.  That said, there are a few ways to [detect if a device is jailbroken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140856/determining-if-an-iphone-is-jail-broken-programatically), or if your app was cracked.  So, your app could detect that and pass that information to your server.

Comment: I don't need to know WHO purchased it ... just that the post is coming from a purchased application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using iTunes Store's in-app purchasing to handle the payment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate some kind of checksum/hash which you thenvalidate on the server, e.g.

http://example.com/something?timestamp=143531&checksum=17

In this example the hash is just the sum of the digits in the timestamp but you'd probably want to use something a bit more secure.