# device token is coming (null) only for few users in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

there is notification feature in my application , its working for all.But only for few members device token itself is coming null.Can anyone help me please to resolve this issue? They are using iOS 9.2 version and device is iPhone 6 and 5s.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Try by restarting device twice.

Comment: When app ask for push notification permission and user deny (Don't Allow) then didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate method not call. So you will not get device token value.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I asked them to restart device and delete app and install it again , but still they have same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

May be this will also work for iOS version greater than 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

*Two possibilities*

***One***

*You missed below code for iOS 8 and above*

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    NSLog(@"ios8 app");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    NSLog(@"lower ios8 app");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

### OR

***Two***

*User click Don't allow for Push*

---

### Edit 1

***If this is happening with some users, then those users iPhone are Jailbroken.*** *Make sure who get device token as null are not Jailbroken*

### Edit 2

To check if jailbroken or not

```
NSString *path = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];

if (fileExists) {
    //device is jailbroken
} else {
    //device is not jailbroken
}
```

[Reference](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6656)

***OR***

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
if ([info objectForKey: @"SignerIdentity"] != nil)
{
/* do something */
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140856/determining-if-an-iphone-is-jail-broken-programatically)

Comment: Hello sir thank you for your response,currently i am using same code.Its perfectly working for all users,but only for few users device token itself is null.

Comment: @veebha : did they click ***Don't Allow*** when prompt for push?

Comment: Ok sir ,Is there a specific way to check their mobiles are jailbroken?

Answer (score 1):

go to settings -> your app -> Notifications -> toggle on Allow Notification
or try

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert| UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
}
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m