# What mechanism can I use to permit only purchased iOS apps to access a webservice?

Tags: ios, web-services

I'm developing a server to provide online services to an iOS app. We want to limit access to this server to those who have actually purchased the app.

When Apps are purchased from the MacOS App Store, the app store packages a receipt in the app's bundle when it delivers it. We can then send this receipt to our server which can validate that the app is legitimate.

Does the iOS App Store do anything similar? Is there a receipt available for the purchase of the app itself? I know about In-App purchases, but we want this service to be accessible to all purchasers of the app itself; we don't want them to have to take extra steps, or spend extra money, after buying the app.

Does anybody know of a mechanism to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

when purchasing an iOS app you dont get any type of receipts that you can process, i would suggest to implement some other solution to limit the access, like using user tokens, but the solution wont be as simple as in Mac

Answer (score 0):

You could make it free and have them pay for an in-app purchase if they want to use the online services, but this is beside the point.

To answer your question, there are ways to detect if the app is "cracked" or just plain stop it from being cracked such as this: http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/anticrack-prevent-iphone-apps-cracked

Comment: Unfortunately, with the new 'clutch' cracking algorithm, this appears to no longer work.

Comment: You could try one of the bread and butter methods such as finding the size of the Info.plist file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903157/get-filesize-of-info-plist-to-prevent-piracy or even more advanced, you could find the SHA1 hash of the Info.plist..