# iPhone sdk - owners name?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, piracy

Is there a way in the iPhone sdk to get the name of the contact who own's the phone?
I see that my app has been cracked, and I would like to update a release which checks to see if it a cracked version and then display the following:

Hello (Persons name). I see you are using a cracked version of (Application Name). If you like this application, please support the me by purchasing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like previous poster mentioned, you can't get the user's name. You can, however, get the phone number by doing

> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]

Taken from [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/01/iphone-dev-user-phone-numbers.ars)

Also regarding copy-protection: problem with iPhone app copy-protection is that Apple does not provide public docs for distribution format or anything even remotely related. So if you base your checks around those undocumented things, you are really juggling on a mine field. Ultimately Apple should really fix this broken system.

Answer (score 4):

StackOverflow: *[Reducing Piracy of iPhone Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)*

Answer (score 1):

That's not available because that's a privacy issue.

(I know, there's some irony there, considering your user just cracked your app, but I digress...)

There's lots of discussion about anti-cracking measures. [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/03/developer-fights-iphone-app-piracy-by-turning-cracks-into-demos.ars) has a story about one developer. Try Google or Apple's Dev Forums ([thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/12773)).