# How can avoid to iphone application cracking?

Tags: cracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reducing piracy of iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)

i built an application for iphone and i want to avoid cracking my app ... like this :

[alt text http://www.freezpic.com/pics/b8d3f07a6a708de18033394010adee8d.PNG](http://www.freezpic.com/pics/b8d3f07a6a708de18033394010adee8d.PNG)

i donn't  problem with running on jail broken iphone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to remove the posts about your stolen app on warez sites but I used the DCMA to get the file removed from the download sites Info on what to do if your app is cracked/stolen jailbroken
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725262/info-on-what-to-do-if-your-app-is-cracked-stolen-jailbroken