# How to check if my iPhone app is hacked/cracked?

Tags: iphone, security

I'm wondering if there are some ways to check if my application is hacked?

I mean, I don't really want to prevent my application from hacking, but I would like to list all iPhone (UUID) that use my hacked application.

Comment: Sounds like a privacy violation to me. Apple won't approve any apps that sniff out phone numbers, even to deter hacking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929166/how-to-programmatically-determine-if-drm-was-removed-from-iphone-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reducing piracy of iPhone applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [mtiks](http://mtiks.com). They do free piracy monitoring, but you'll have to re-release your app to the appstore. If you don't have anything setup currently, you're not going to be able to tell who's using it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if encryption was removed from you app bundle or any other changes were made.

If you don't prevent your app from being cracked by any different behavior, such as not working, this makes your detection code much harder to find.