# secure ios app from hack - objective-c

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to make app not launchable if it has been cracked and installed from installous? I don't want to see my app in installous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that easy and it not answerable within some words or code snippets.
But you might check this:

http://www.shmoopi.net/ios-anti-piracy/iphone-piracy-protection-code-tutorial-2/

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7667

http://thwart-ipa-cracks.blogspot.com/2008/11/detection.html

The read also here:

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/05/ignore-everything-youve-heard-about-app-store-piracy/

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to detect whether your app is running on a jailbreaked device or whether your app has been modified (aka cracked). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727976/how-to-detect-a-cracked-iphone-app-and-a-jailbroken-device-different-methods) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications) for example.

From my point of view all you are getting by using these methods is a waste of time. Maybe you can make it harder for potential crackers and keep away the script kiddies. But you won't get that far that no talented cracker on earth would be unable to crack your app. Even one single cracker on earth who's able and motivated to crack your app is enough to upload it to hundred's of sites.

If really big companies fail at protecting their apps I really doubt that you will achieve it... so: wasted time which should be better spend on improving your app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, because the part of cracking your application is to remove all restrictions (registration, detection of jailbreak, ...).

Comment: it is possible to prevent from cracking your iOS app with the normal easy steps. But it might take some actions and understanding.