# How to encrypt application from being cracked. - iphone

Tags: iphone, encryption, jailbreak

I just was looking at some of the cracked applications. I want to know how can we encrypt our application from being cracked so easily. I also saw a video tutorial to crack the application using a simple software.

Is there any way to protect the paid app from crackers?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reducing piracy of iPhone applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some expensive libraries to protect the app.
But, in my opinion, since a pirated copy should not be treated as a lost sale, the price of such libraries it's not worth.

edit: i just found [anticrack](http://www.cocoanetics.com/anticrack/) that has a reasonable price

Answer (score 2):

Implementing protection on your side is risky. You could detect a modified binary or disabled signature checking and disable some features (like Game Center), but there is a slight risk of penalizing and dissatisfying a real customer, which IMHO is worse. Focus on creating a great app instead, and you could convert a "pirate" to a customer.