# How to prevent ipa file/iphone application from being cracked to source?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, reverse-engineering

from one of the stackexchange questions [Here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source),its proved that we can decompile the iphone application to its source,Now here comes the question how can we protect the ipa file/iphone application from cracking to its source?i have already verified this answers 
[here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)
[method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341408/how-to-encrypt-application-from-being-cracked-iphone?rq=1)
but sad thing is it fails to protect the code,any updates to prevent app to source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really.

The iOS runtime on the device needs to be able to interpret the binary, so the binary has to be there, unencrypted and ready to run.

You could obfuscate it, by running it through a tool that scrambles method names, property names and so on.  .NET and Java have tools that do this but I'm not aware of any for Objective-C, so I think you're on your own.

(Tools like anticrack, the one you linked to, will work for a short time until someone comes up with a way to reverse what anticrack does - but because your app eventually has to be there in a format the runtime is ready to run, all you can do is make it more difficult.  It's like the age-old arms race of pirates vs protection mechanism in desktop applications).

Comment: +1 for anticrack loophole,and sir according to the answer(reverse engineering question) the binary info can be fetched  by following the steps of 3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

This has been much discussed. Generally, you make more money spending time improving or promoting your app, then spending time trying to prevent it from being cracked in any way.