# Dataprotection - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, security

Have any one worked on data protection in iPhone - iOS. Can you share the details with me regarding that?

Comment: what do you mean by data protection?

Comment: Are you talking about anti-piracy measures for apps?

Comment: @Rakesh -  try this link its a device configuration http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175 .i need to implement through code

Comment: @Tovi - Yes Can u get me the details how to implement it.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/ .Apple has given the api for it so any one get me the idea in this.

Comment: Any one any idea on how, for instance the official Twitter client, hide there bundle information from apps like iphoneExplorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anti-piracy measures, I should redirect you to the following stackoverflow question:

[reducing piracy of iphone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications)

Though some of the techniques described there are outdated. For instance, it is no longer useful to just check SignerIdentity key in your Info.plist.

If you want more advanced stuff, take a look at this thread:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/36330-iphone-piracy-protection-code-2-another-tutorial.html

Comment: Hi - Can you get me the sample for the same.