# iPhone - Did the user purchase my app?

Tags: iphone, security

I'm trying to figure out how to verify that the user purchased my app before allowing them to register an account on my server.  I failed with my web search - all I found was references to in-app purchase.. Is there some kind of receipt on the phone? Is it safe to send to my server etc..

EDIT - You can't query Apple for information on the users who have purchased the app? An email? anything??

EDIT2 -

Heres the deal, you can use the app all you want. But theres an optional ability to work with my server. This is expensive, if pirates start using my server I can't handle it.  So I need to be able to authorize the user at my server. I'm guessing in app payment is what I'll have to use as that allows me to verify a purchase against a user/password on my site, I just didn't want the user to have to go through the hassle of the in-app payment and allow them to purchase the app upfront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of registration with backend from within the app.

Comment: Yeah, but you still don't know if the app was actually purchased and someone could use your registration page on your website without having an app as well. I assumed Apple would have a way to contact my server at the time of the purchase.

Comment: We did this in several apps. When receiving the iTunes receipt we register this on our backend (where the user has access with credentials generated in a registration process from within the app). But Apple isn't the biggest fan of user registration forms within the applications :(

Comment: I simply have to use in app purchase so that I can connect the transaction to the user on my site via the receipt as noted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

You could check to make sure your app hasn't been cracked instead? - (see top answer [Reducing piracy of iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846309/reducing-piracy-of-iphone-applications))

Comment: Really? Simply having Apple give me an email would allow me to verify every user who attempts to register eliminating the problem completely no?

Comment: As far as I'm aware for app purchases apple will only tell you which nation's app store the purchase was made, but won't tell you anything about the purchaser.

Comment: @Mark, Apple protect the privacy of the user that is why I love them. But if you got my iTunes account email address and I want to use another email to create that account? Also, not know what your app is, what if I bought the app for my kid? I don't my kid using my email address to _register_.